# Microcontroller switch between output pins sequentially (in a loop ) at every input pulse on PORTA.0

Tags: microcontroller

I'm coding a microcontroller "PIC 16F877" to be a register switch for 30 LED displays to connect their common cathode with ground .. I don't have problem with the circuit of the PBC bit-4 coding to display numbers as it takes signals from serial port pins (1, 2, 4, 8) and pin (16) is a pulse switcher to tell the 16F877 to switch between output ports sequentially..

PORTA.0 - The input switcher pulse --- > Serial port pin 16

and From PORTA.1 tp PORTB.7, all are outputs

At every signal pulse the microcontroller will check on PORTA.0, it will send a 5v ( logic 1 ) on ports from PORTA.1 to PORTB.7 which are 30 output ports, the current has to be cut off when a new pulse detected on PORTA.0

My code is :

```
       char cnt = 0;

    void main () {
      ANSEL = 0;
      ANSELH = 0;
      PORTA = 0;
      TRISA = 0b100000; // PORTA.0 as input, PORTA.1 to PORTA.5 as outputs
      PORTB = 0;
      TRISB = 0;  // as a sample code assume we have 6 PORTB outputs
                  // Plus the above 5 PORTA outputs to run 11 LED Displays
                  // I want to declare an array as below

     string prts[12] = {PORTA.1, PORTA.2, PORTA.3, PORTA.4, PORTA.5, PORTB.0, PORTB.1, PORTB.2, PORTB.3, PORTB.4, PORTB.5, PORTB.6};

do {
  if ( PORTA.0 = 0xFF ) {
        prts[cnt -- 1] = 0x00;  // previous output = low
        prts[cnt] = 0xFF;       // next output = high
        cnt++;
}
while(1)
}
```

as a sample code above, I want to start from PORTA.0 to PORTB.6 sequentially ( at every PORTA.0 pulse from serial port pin 16 ), the microcontroller will apply a 5v current on a next selected port from the array by "cnt" and 0v on the previously applied 5v port .. and to return to PORTA.0 to start the loop again ( which I couldn't do by FOR ) .. and thus

o

Comment: A pedant writes: a 5V current is a meaningless thing to say. It's a voltage of 5V that causes a current to flow. I'm not sure what the problem is you're having is though.

Comment: It isn't clear what your question is.  However, it is clear that your prts[] array will not work, as you'd need an array of pointers to ports, not a string.  Also you'll use a pointer out of bounds if you don't clip cnt to be a max of 11...  You could just consider an array of structs, (one element for PORTA, one element for PORTB).  Then you could do PORTA = prts[cnt].portA; PORTB = prts[cnt].portB;

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25857083/using-a-string-array-in-a-c-loop-to-switch-between-pic-i-o-pins